# If I'm making a UITableViewCell slideable (for quick delete) how do I make it so it's still tappable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I've successfully made it that my UITableViewCell can be slid right and left to mark the cell as read, or to delete it (sort of like how the Reeder app does it) but now it doesn't allow me to simply tap it. How do I allow it to be tapped as well?

I used [this article](http://gregprice.co.uk/blog/?p=280) for the structure of the concept, so more information is available there.

I implemented the sliding as follows:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    _firstTouchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

    // Holds the value of how far away from the first touch the finger has moved
    CGFloat xPos;

    // If the first touch point is left of the current point, it means the user is moving their finger right and the cell must move right
    if (_firstTouchPoint.x < touchPoint.x) {
        xPos = touchPoint.x - _firstTouchPoint.x;

        if (xPos <= 0) {
            xPos = 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        xPos = -(_firstTouchPoint.x - touchPoint.x);

        if (xPos >= 0) {
            xPos = 0;
        }
    }

    // Change our cellFront's origin to the xPos we defined
    CGRect frame = self.cellFront.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(xPos, 0);
    self.cellFront.frame = frame;

}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self springBack];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self springBack];
}

- (void)springBack {
    CGFloat cellXPositionBeforeSpringBack = self.cellFront.frame.origin.x;

    CGRect frame = self.cellFront.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        self.cellFront.frame = frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

    if (cellXPositionBeforeSpringBack >= 80 || cellXPositionBeforeSpringBack <= -80) {
        NSLog(@"YA");
    }
}
```

When I tap it though, nothing happens.

Comment: It would be easier if you just use the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` or even better if you use the table view `delete` functionality.

Comment: Neither of those provide the functionality necessary for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use UIPanGestureRecognizer.

the touchesBegan approach is so old.
With the pan Gesture you will not lose the touch event on your cell.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to solve it, is actually to build your own gesture for sliding right and left.
After you build it, just add this gesture to the view, and add the tap gesture as well.

If you allow the both gestures (tap gesture and slide gesture) to live simultaneously by implementing the 'shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer' method, iOS will take care of it for you very easily.

Here how to build custom gesture recogniser:

http://blog.federicomestrone.com/2012/01/31/creating-custom-gesture-recognisers-for-ios/